# Netlogo: Creating subsets of agentsets of a particular breed

Tags: subset, netlogo

I am still new to Netlogo, but I can not find an explanation for this in the documentation.

I am trying to create a subset of an agentset that only contains one type of breed.  It would seem that I could use "with" to perform this, but for some reason that does not work.

This code works:

```
ask link-neighbors with [shape = "person"][
  set pmt (pmt + dist)
]
```

But this code does not:

```
ask link-neighbors with [breed = "psngrs"][
  set pmt (pmt + dist)
]
```

How can I create a subset of an agentset with only this particular breed?

Thanks!

Comment: Do not put the breed name is quotes. (That creates a string, but you want the special agentset of that name.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is showing as unanswered, though Alan gave the correct answer in a comment. So, just so I stop clicking on this thinking it is unanswered, I'm going to reiterate what he said as an answer. Alan, if you add your comment as answer, I'll happily delete mine.

Anyway, just get rid of the quotes around the breed name, like so:

```
link-neighbors with [breed = psngrs]
```